# Find the points on the graph of $f(x) = 12(x + 9) − (x + 9)^3$ where the tangent line is horizontal.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I cannot figure out how to get started on this question. Would I First simplify, and then take the derivative? Please help!

Comment: That's a way to start. After you simplify, you should realize that the function is linear (its graph is a straight line), so its graph is already its own  tangent line everywhere.

Comment: Is your function properly typed? Right now it appears to be a linear function...

Comment: While you can solve this problem by inspection, with a more complex function, you're correct, you'd simplify then take the derivative. The derivative is the slope of the graph of the function at each point, so solve for the derivative being 0 (the "slope" of a horizontal line). If you do that here, you'll find what @MPW commented.

Comment: I think the function is $f(x)=12(x+9)-(x+9)^3$

Comment: Please clarify: Is that last supposed to be $(x+9)3$ or $(x+9)^3$? I am voting to close this question but will remove my vote if you clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f(x)=12(x+9)-(x+9)^3$$ and differentiate to get
$$f'(x)=12-3(x+9)^2\tag{1}$$ then set $(1)$ equal to zero to find the stationary points (where the gradient is zero, a *horizontal line*) such that $$12-3(x+9)^2=0 \implies (x+9)^2=4 \implies x+9=\pm2 \implies x=-7,-11$$ Then $$f(-7)=16$$ and $$f(-11)=-16$$ So points (coordinates) where the tangent line is horizontal are $(-7,16)$ and $(-11,-16)$

Answer (score 0):

If $$f(x)=12(x+9)-(x+9)^3,$$ then 
$$f'(x)=12-3(x+9)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x+9$ appears twice in $f(x)$, which strongly suggests we should consider $f(x - 9) = 12x - x^3$, which is the graph of $f(x)$ translated right by $9$ units.

Thus $f'(x-9) = 0 \Rightarrow 12 - 3x^2 = 0 \Rightarrow x = ±2$, so the critical points are $(2, 16)$ and $(-2,-16)$. Now translate left by $9$ units to find the critical points of the original function: $(-7, 16)$ and $(-11, -16)$.